# How to grab record id in block within model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a form that submits some custom attributes for a post. Lets call it "thing_attributes".

Lets also say that I'm posting it from an existing post.

In my Post model I then have the following:

```
  def thing_attributes=(things)
      mybook = Book.new      
      mybook.title = things
      mybook.post_id = ?
  end
```

My actual code is more complicated - so I realize this seems asinine, but it makes sense in my execution.

Either way, as you can see I have no idea how to get that post_id in there, from the post that the form is being submitted from.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If that's being set on an existing post (say, an edit form), then you can just call

`id` or `self.id`

But maybe a better way would be to do this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books # and book belongs_to :post

  def thing_attributes=(things)
    self.books.create(:title => things)
  end
end
```

And the post_id should automatically be set for you.

Comment: thanks man! that worked perfect (went with the top solution as what I'm working is ridiculously complicated - but good info on the second solution!) - marking this correct in 5 min when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

If Post has_many books, and Book belongs_to :post, then:

```
post.books.build
```

should be used instead of:

```
Book.new
```

and it will set the post ID for you, since it's an association.

Otherwise, since thing_attributes is an instance method of Post, `self.id` will return the current post's ID.